# My menu is hiding although I defined it

Tags: java, android, xml

Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_notifications" />

</menu>
```

My Java code:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
    mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
             //   mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
            //    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
          //      mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

When I run this code I can't show the menu.
I searched for examples but I saw that need to be correct code!

I can't understanding what is my problem??

Comment: Post the xml file of your layout where you used the BottomNavigationView.

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, you have only posted a portion of the code necessary to display the menu. As Nabin Bhandari said, you should post the BottomNavigationView in your layout (as exemplified in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **menu** for your navigation view, you can do so in the NavigationView properties.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Don't forget to add the **namespace**:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a BottomNavigationView, you need to place it in the XML layout for your Activity. Adapted from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html), you could use the following code:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

where `my_navigation_items` points to the XML menu resource you included in your question. I have put `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, but this will only work if the parent is the top level View in the Activity. I would put the two `xmlns` required namespaces at the top of the document.